# Multiple SQL queries C# using Oracle DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I need to run several queries inside one function. My working code for single query is as below:

**C# Code:**

```
try
    {
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.0.0.24)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=DEVL)));User Id=aaziz;Password=123211;";
        con.Open();
        string cmdQuery = "Insert into M.person (RED_NO, USED_FLAG) VALUES ('12', '0')";
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdQuery);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Dispose();
    }
catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
```

**How to modify it to accommodate multiple SQL queries?**

Comment: Have you tried adding a second query? Did it not work?

Comment: That's what I asking how to perform it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try
{
    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.0.0.24)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=DEVL)));User Id=aaziz;Password=123211;";
    con.Open();
    string cmdQuery = "Insert into M.person (RED_NO, USED_FLAG) VALUES ('12', '0')";
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdQuery);
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT NEW QUERY HERE";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT NEW QUERY HERE";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT NEW QUERY HERE";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT NEW QUERY HERE";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
```